Raspberry PI 4, Java, Pi4j: Unable to load libgpiod.so
I am trying to get Java and Pi4j to work on my new Rasperry Pi 4 B.
I followed pi4j's instructions exactly. With jbang or maven I have same problem.
The pi4j-example-minimal ist compiled and packaged without errors. When I try to run it
I get the error:
[main] ERROR com.pi4j.library.gpiod.util.NativeLibraryLoader - unable to load [llibgpiod.so] using path [lib/aarch64/pi4j-gpiod/libgpiod.so]
There is actually no /lib/aarch64/ directory on the computer und nowhere I can find a file named libgpiod.so
I'm really disappointed that not even the Minimal-Example works.
Can anyone help me and tell me, what is going wrong!
Thanks in advance!
Andi
My system:
Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev. 1.5
Pi4j-basic-os on the sd-card (new from today, updated)
java version openjdk version 17.0.13 64 Bit Server
jbang version 0.119.0
I did the following:
git clone https://github.com/Pi4J/pi4j-jbang
Downloaded the pi4j-example-minimal from github
sudo which jbang Pi4JMinimalExample.java
Same problem when I did it with maven

Is that library installed? sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep libgpiod

Apparently not - no output.

Well it's not going to work without it. I suggest you look very carefully at the installation instructions

I'm working with Maven for the first time - I thought Maven takes care of all dependencies now ???

Maven (usually) doesn't take care of native code. Only Java code
